# How to prevent zxcvbn.min.js in wordpress from loading?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to optimize my website my wordpress websie, when I check my WP page size, from the total 900KB - 400KB is zxcvbn.min.js I learnt that this script is used to make sure that the password is strong but I do not need it.

I tried the recommendation on this page, but it doesn't work for me- [disable zxcvbn.min.js in wordpress and woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769522/disable-zxcvbn-min-js-in-wordpress-and-woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove it. The problem is it also causes a 404 error and 1 second page speed delay (Time to First Byte) for me...

```
function my_add_frontend_scripts() {
// Deregister script about password strenght meter ~ 800kb
wp_dequeue_script('wc-password-strength-meter');
wp_deregister_script('wc-password-strength-meter');

wp_register_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/custom-script.js', array('jquery'), 1, false );
wp_enqueue_script('custom-script');
}
```

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_frontend_scripts');

Im still searching for a solution. I CANNOT BELIEVE that Wordpress/WooCommerce haven't come up with a built in setting in the admin dashboard to turn this PW strength meter off. UNREAL

Comment: I added the script in my functions.php page using Snippets plugin but it doesn't work.